# OpenSSL compilation issue with SSL_export_keying_material()

Tags: ssl, compilation, openssl, darwin

I am trying to call the method SSL_export_keying_material() from an SSL Client program. However calling this method fails the program compilation. I get the following error. How can I over come this compilation error?

```
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -o withssl -lssl -lcrypto /var/folders/1b/smlgh1256t95yw11pqs2hz380000gn/T/withssl-08785c.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSL_export_keying_material", referenced from:
      _main in withssl-08785c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I over come this compilation error?

You need to install a recent version of OpenSSL. By default, Apple provides version 0.9.8 and it does not supply `SSL_export_keying_material`:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libssl.dylib | grep SSL_export_keying_material
$
```

And here's from my copy of 1.0.1i:

```
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/lib/libssl.a | grep SSL_export_keying_material
...
0000000000002810 T _SSL_export_keying_material
00000000000068c8 S _SSL_export_keying_material.eh
```

---

Here's how to fetch and install OpenSSL 1.0.1i in `/usr/local/ssl`. There's other `config` options available. See [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki for details.

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1i.tar.gz
tar xzf openssl-1.0.1i.tar.gz 
cd openssl-1.0.1i
export KERNEL_BITS=64
./config enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make
sudo make install
```

After that, be sure you compile and link against the OpenSSL gear in `/usr/local/ssl`.

---

Also, Apple linkers ignore `LD_PRELOAD`, `-Bstatic`, and `-Wl,--rpath`. Be ***sure*** to use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (the OS X equivalent to `LD_PRELOAD`). Otherwise, you will compile against 1.0.1 (from `/usr/local/ssl`), but link against 0.9.8 (from `/usr/lib`) at runtime. See [`dyld(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) for some information on Apple's runtime link editor.

If you compile against 1.0.1 but runtime link against 0.9.8, then you will encounter unexplained crashes. The reason is not readily apparent, but its because 0.9.8 and 1.0.1 are *not* binary compatible.

I usually toss this into my code to guard against it:

```
long version = SSLeay();
ASSERT(version == OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER);
if (version != OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER)
{
    /* Handle incorrect version at runtime */
}
```

The code above checks that the compile time version is the same as the runtime version.

Comment: Assert is giving an error though: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_ASSERT", referenced from: _main in withssl-b70c9a.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: @kani - `ASSERT` is my custom assert. If you don't have one, use `#define ASSERT(x) assert(x)`. Then include `<assert.h>` or `<cassert>`. You can read about the ASSERT I use at OWASP's [C-Based Toolchain Hardening](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/C-Based_Toolchain_Hardening#ASSERT). Effectively, in debug builds, my `ASSERT` calls `SIGTRAP` (to snap the debugger) rather than `SIGABRT` (to kill the program).